# SHA256 in Crypto++ library

Tags: c++, crypto++

Let us focus on SHA256.

According to the following website,
http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm, the 'Binary hash' of 123 is 3d73c0...... and the 'String hash' of 123 is a665a4.......

I can obtain the 'String hash' by using the library of crypto++ as the following code:

```
CryptoPP::SHA256 hash;
string digest;
CryptoPP::StringSource d1pk("123", true, new CryptoPP::HashFilter(hash, new HexEncoder(new CryptoPP::StringSink(digest))));

cout<< "digest : " << digest <<endl;
```

How can I obtain the 'Binary hash' by using the library of crypto++?

Comment: Using that tool's "binary hash" the string `123` is converted into the two bytes `12,03` then hashed, its a completely different thing

Comment: Is there a particular reason you want the 'binary hash'. It looks like thats just an input mechanism for their website. But if you specify _why_ then we may be able to help.

Comment: @ Alex K. Yes, it is a completely different thing. The above code shows that one can obtain a digest from a string "123". The library of crypto++ provides a method to obtain a digest from bytes as an input?

Answer (score 0):

The website you linked is a hash tool, and allows for input as either string or bytes.

When you enter a string it will get the bytes of it and then hash that, so the "Binary Hash" is no different. It accepts data in another format, hexadecimal, and converts that to bytes to be hashed.

This is the best explanation of what is going on, but I can not be completely definitive without seeing their source.